# Yandex maps в angular 4

Tags: angular2, yandex-maps-api

Как правильно отображать карту в angular 4?
Если подключить глобально данные, тогда при роутинге карта не работает, а только при ручном обновлении страницы карта отображается.

```
ymaps.ready(init);
      var myMap;

      function init() {
        myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
            center: [55.76, 37.64],
            zoom: 7
        });
    }
```

Может кто подскажет как правильно подключить всё это в компонент, чтобы карта работа при роутинге

Comment: можешь сделать свою директиву или компонент или взять уже готовый компонент

Comment: Благодарен за ответ

Comment: Это вообще-то комментарий был :-) так как в итоге решил свою проблему?

Comment: Да как и посоветовал, написал свою директиву.

Comment: тогда можешь добавить свой ответ, и в нем описать что сделал и хотя бы в общих чертах какая директива полчилась

Answer (score 1):

```js
declare var ymaps: any;
declare var jQuery: any;

interface YandexMap extends MVCObject {
    constructor(el: HTMLElement, opts?: any): void;
    geoObjects: any;
}

interface MVCObject { addListener(eventName: string, handler: Function): MapsEventListener; }
interface MapsEventListener { remove(): void; }
@Component({
    selector: 'maps-all',
    template: `
        <div #yamaps></div>      
    `
})
export class MapsAllComponent implements OnInit {

    myMap: Promise<YandexMap> = new Promise<YandexMap>((resolve: () => void) => { this._mapResolver = resolve; });
    private _mapResolver: (value?: YandexMap) => void;
    options: any = {
            center: [56.316203, 43.987447],
            zoom: 10,
            controls: ['zoomControl', 'searchControl', 'typeSelector',  'fullscreenControl']
        };

    @ViewChild('yamaps') el: ElementRef;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        
        ymaps.ready().done(() => {
            const map = new ymaps.Map(this.el.nativeElement, this.options);
            this._mapResolver(<YandexMap>map);
 
            map.events.add('click', this.clickMaps, this);           
        });
        
    }

    clickMaps(e: any) {
        let coords = e.get('coords');
    }
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]